# get type of what is stored as text in a python variable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

```
In[66]:  type(numpy.core)
Out[66]: module
```

Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:25:24) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

```
j = "numpy.core"    
j
type(j)
Out[65]: str
```

Want to be able to get the `type` of `numpy.core` and not the `type` of the variable `j`. In other words, I want `type(j)` function to return `module` not `str`

Please read the extra information below about why I would want the above functionality. May be irrelevant, please ignore if so.

```
funcattrmeth = []
funcattrmeth = dir(numpy)
len(funcattrmeth)
for i in funcattrmeth:
    j = 'numpy.' + i
    k = type(j)
    print ("subentity " + j + " of type " + k )
```

Expected (shortened) Output

```
subentity numpy.var of type function
subentity numpy.vdot of type builtin_function_or_method
subentity numpy.vectorize of type type
subentity numpy.version of type module
subentity numpy.void of type type
```

Immense thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

The extra information is pretty helpful because this is basically an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/141542). What you are actually trying to do is iterate through the members of a module.

As with any object, module or not, we can access a member using [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). For example:

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> a.title()
'Foo'
>>> getattr(a, 'title')()
'Foo'
```

With this knowledge, we can also access members of a module:

```
for memberName in dir(numpy):
    member = getattr(numpy, memberName)
    print('numpy.{0} of type {1}'.format(memberName, type(member)))
```

Gives this output:

```
…
numpy.ldexp of type <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
numpy.left_shift of type <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
numpy.less of type <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
numpy.less_equal of type <class 'numpy.ufunc'>
numpy.lexsort of type <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
numpy.lib of type <class 'module'>
numpy.linalg of type <class 'module'>
numpy.linspace of type <class 'function'>
numpy.little_endian of type <class 'bool'>
…
```

As Jon Clements mentioned in the comments, if you were to call `getattr` on every member anyway, you can also just use [`vars()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) instead of `dir()` to return a *dictionary* of all members directly. So you get both the name and the value of each member that way:

```
for memberName, member in vars(numpy).items():
    print('numpy.{0} of type {1}'.format(memberName, type(member)))
```

Comment: Or you can avoid the `getattr` and use `vars` - eg... `for name, obj in vars(numpy).items(): print(...)`...

Comment: Useful! Can type(j) return module at all?

Comment: @user3146086 `type()` returns the *type* of an object. That type can be a module yes, but using `type()` you will never get an actual module object back which you can use for something useful.

Comment: Also - depending what exactly you want to do there's `inspect.getmembers` and co...